# Dynamically typed file access via templates or pure virtual base class inheritance?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, pure-virtual

I would like to access a **file that contains key->value pairs of various types** (currently only `double`, but may be `long double` in the future, for instance).
File access may happen between keys, at which point some (rather complex) interpolation will be done. Access speed is very important.

I see two possibilites to implement this:

1. Use **templates** to write a generic reader for this type of file, using the key and value types as template parameters. This will be very fast and nice to implement, however, it requires people to know the types in the files when opening. 
   To open a file without knowing the excact types, I would need to implement a **wrapper** opening various types of files and casting the types, which would mean a few casts per access of the file.
   The downside is that this wrapper will be quite ugly and large, because it has to include a **special case for every possible combination of types**. I would probably auto-generate the code for this wrapper or use some preprocessor magic.
2. From the computer science point of view, it would be much nicer to **wrap the key and value type into classes** with a common abstract base class and handle pointers to these classes all the time.
   This will make the usage of files of unknown types much easier, though it involves dynamic casting all the time.
   The problem is that the aforementioned interpolation will require the construction of a lot of these wrapper classes together with a large amount of virtual function calls, which will probably affect the access speed significantly to the negative.
   I am also hesitant to add this flexibility that nobody may ever use (after all, `double` is the only thing that is required right now).

What would you do? Do you have better suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on Factory deasign pattern. In factory you will pass the header -> type of the file and it will generate an reader for this file. So you have to define an interface IFile and implement it in your classes PdfFile, TxtFile, DocxFile and so on.

You could use abstract factory or factory method depends on your requirements
I will give you an example of abstract factory:

```
class IFileFactory{
public:
 virtual IFile* getInstance( const std::string& fileHeader ) = 0; //header in hex representation.
};

class ConcreteFileFactory : public IFileFactory{
 IFile* getInstance( const std::string& fileHeader ){
    if( fileHeader == "33442233" )
    {
       return new PdfFile();
    }else if( fileHeader == "4455533" ){
       return new DocxFile();
    }
    //......
    throw FactoryException("Unknown file");
 }
};
```

Comment: Yep, the key thing here is to have a header in the file to show what types to use to instantiate the reader for the rest.  You can use a factory pattern, but you don't have to.  (But you should!!)  : )

Comment: Well yes, thank you, this is how I wanted to implement the wrapper around the templated design. So you would go for the templated design and write a wrapper using the factory pattern?